# Creating a net cash flow

Tags: python

So I'm running into some problems when I take a cashflow and try to create a net CF if there are two cashflows in the same time period.

Basically, I want to go from this:

```
time=[1,2,3,3]
cf=[100,500,1000,-500]
```

to:

```
time=[1,2,3]
cf=[100,500,500]
```

Any suggestions would be helpful as I'm very new to python.
Thanks.

Comment: Will `time` always be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

time=[1,2,3,3] 
cf=[100,500,1000,-500]

result = defaultdict(int)

for num,i in enumerate(time):
    result[i] += cf[num]   

time2 = list(result.keys())
cf2 = list(result.values())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand the basics now but lets say that time is pulled a column in excel (time[]) and cf is pulled from the adjacent column. I won't know if there is a repeated time or not so is there a way to get it to work that way? I tried to implement this method but it came up as the normal cf instead of cf2.

Comment: I think xlrd returns cell values as a string, will this change how to do this?

Comment: this method will also work if there are no repeated times.  It simply takes a cf value and adds it to dict with that time key.  If there are no time repeats, it just adds each cf value to the time key once.  If it is returning string values, you may need to cast them to `int()` first. Check the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) for `int()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> tm = [1,2,3,3]
>>> cf = [100,500,1000,-500]
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for t, ca in zip(tm, cf):
...     c[t] += ca
...     
>>> c
Counter({2: 500, 3: 500, 1: 100})
```

Use `sorted` and unzipping on `c.iteritems` to get the expected output:

```
>>> cf, tm = zip(*sorted(c.iteritems()))
>>> cf
(1, 2, 3)
>>> tm
(100, 500, 500)
```

If `tm` list is always sorted then you can also use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, izip
>>> tm_1 = []
>>> cf_1 = []
>>> for k, g in groupby(izip(tm, cf), key=lambda x:x[0]):
...     tm_1.append(k)
...     cf_1.append(sum(x[1] for x in g))
...     
>>> tm_1
[1, 2, 3]
>>> cf_1
[100, 500, 500]
```

<sub>`time` is a built-in module, don't use it as a variable name.</sub>

Comment: A `Counter()` is somewhat overkill; a `defaultdict(int)` object would fill the same function without the extra functionality that is quite out of scope here.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't my greatest work in style, but it fits your needs.

```
time=[1,2,3,3]
cf=[100,500,1000,-500]
transactions = zip(time, cf)
cf = list(set(sf))
cf.sort()

final_cf = []
for time in cf:
    total_period = 0
    for element in transactions:
        if element[0] == time:
            total_period += element[1]
    final_cf.append(total_period)
```

Another approach is using a dict:

```
time=[1,2,3,3]
cf=[100,500,1000,-500]
transactions = zip(time, cf)
cf_unique = list(set(cf))
cf_unique.sort()
result = dict()

for moment in cf_unique:
result[moment] = 0
for transaction in transactions:
    if transaction[0] == moment:
        result[moment] += transaction

final_cf = result.items()
```

In both cases i used just the "basic" data structures in python. I used a set to eliminate duplicated time, and then made a ordered list of it. Then a iteration to collect all transactions that happened in each time frame.